# If n and m are sums of two squares so is $\frac{n}{m}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, alternative-proof, sums-of-squares

So I found the following post regarding this problem, but I don't find the solution to be helpful at all, so I decided to ask the question again. Furthermore, my question is a bit different than the one asked in the post shown below.

[if m and n are sum of squares then so is $\frac{m}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2025874/if-m-and-n-are-sum-of-squares-then-so-is-fracmn)

I have to prove that if n and m are a sum of two squares and if $m\mid n$ then $\frac{n}{m}$  is also a sum of two fractions.

My attempt at a solution:
$n=a^2 + b^2 $
and
$m=x^2 + y^2$
Furthermore, the fraction $\frac{n}{m}=q$ where $q$ is the ratio between both numbers and we are trying to prove that $k$ is also a sum of two squares. I am thinking of also using the fact that  any natural number can be written in the form $n=k^2p_1...p_r$, but I am kind of confused how to do it. Can somebody give me any ideas regarding this problem. Thanks!

Comment: How is your question any different from the one you link to? What do you know about numbers that can be expressed as the sum of two squares?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1445105/589

Answer (score 1):

As a hint to get you started:

Consider the special case of $\frac 1m$ with $m=a^2+b^2$.  Then we have $$\frac 1m=\frac {a^2}{m^2}+\frac {b^2}{m^2}=\left(\frac am\right)^2+\left(\frac bm\right)^2$$

Now try to adapt this to the general case.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me to some extent!